# Ruby disjunction syntax

Tags: ruby

I encountered some code that looks like:

```
(input_array || []).each do |a|
  some stuff
end
```

What is the purpose of `input_array || []`? I would naively think that this would evaluate to a boolean value which would cause `each` to throw an error, but that's clearly not whats happening.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The semantics of || are:

- if the first expression is not nil or false, return it
- if the first expression is nil or false, return the second expression

This is used to provide a default value if the first is nil.

Comment: @Mark Thomas Interesting, in what other contexts can this be used? I imagine it would confuse the parser if you were to try using it in an if statement

Comment: In ruby all objects except `nil` and `false` are considered `true`, so `||` still works as you'd expect in `if` statements

Comment: @jon_simon we also use it to cache assignment, e.g. `foo ||= []` is like `foo = foo || []` (though not exactly, see [what-rubys-double-pipe-or-equals-really-does](http://www.rubyinside.com/what-rubys-double-pipe-or-equals-really-does-5488.html))

Comment: @jon_simon: Why would using a conditional operator in a conditional expression "confuse the parser"? I would be pretty useless if you couldn't use "or" in an "if" condition, don't you think?